# Nagios : event handle for container restart

Tags: nagios

1. I am trying to restart my test-container with shell script. The script  works well when directly executing but not working with Nagios.
2. This command is working while executing with Nagios:

   echo -e "\n$DATE: ML flow container restarted ." >> /var/log/container-restart.log

Just wants to provide info: The service state change and script execution is working. But the following command is not working:

```
echo "xxxx" | sshpass -p 'xxxx' ssh -tt abc@host 'sudo -S docker start test-container'
```

Need help in figuring out the issue with following command:

```
echo "xxxx" | sshpass -p 'xxxx' ssh -tt abc@host 'sudo -S docker start test-container'
```

Comment: Hi there, I see that you are new here. This site is for programming related question. Your post does not seems to quite fit to that ares. You should use https://serverfault.com/ for that ;-)